# Issue finding euler's number in java

Tags: java, eulers-number

i have to find *e*, which is `1/0!` + `1/1!` + `1/2!` + `1/3!`... + `1/n!` given n as a parameter and i'm having trouble getting the correct answer.

```
public double Factorial(int n) {
        long fact = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            fact *= i;
        }
        return fact;
    }



    public double euler(int n) {
        double y = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x <= n; x++) {
            double e = 1 / Factorial(n);
            y = y + e;
        }
        return y;
```

when i input `10`, this outputs `2.7557319223985893E-6` when i should be getting `2.7182818011463845`. i ran through the code a few times but i can't figure out the issue. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Because you're calculating 1/n! + 1/n! .... (n + 1 times). Replace Factorial(n) with Factorial(x).

Comment: Yeah, change the Factorial(n) to Factorial(x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given in the comments addresses the problem. And since you have the algorithm down you may be interested in the following:

A factorial method is not necessary.  Since each subsequent value of `n!` is `n! * (n+1)` you can work it into your main loop as follows.

```
// initialize fact to 0!
double fact = 1;

// first Euler term 1/0!
double y = fact;

for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
    // next factorial
    fact *= x;
    // subsequent terms
    y += (1 / fact);
}
System.out.println(y);
```

Prints

```
2.7182818011463845
```

And Euler's number is also the **limit of (1 + r)<sup>(1/r)</sup>** as **r** approaches **0**.

```
double r = .000000001;
System.out.println(Math.pow(1 + r, 1/r));
        
2.71828205201156
```